# How to synchronize time in the Linux container with the Windows host

Tags: docker, datetime, time, windows-10

When I run Linux container on the Docker installed on Linux I can synchronize the container datetime with the Linux host datetime using the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro myimage bash
```

How to achieve datetime synchronization when a Linux container is run on Docker installed on Windows 10 ? (let's assume that a docker command is executed from the standard windows console or cmd script).

I know that I can also set datetime in the Linux container (on Linux and Windows ) this way:

```
docker run -it --rm -e TZ=Europe/Berlin myimage
```

but I'm looking for a generic solution.